# Why presentViewController calls viewDidLoad again?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I have `ViewController`, built using storybard and it contains a `UITableView`. When `UITableViewCell` is pressed, I just want to present SomeViewController. In `didSelectRowAt` method I do following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    present(SomeViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

But I checked using debugger, this calls `viewDidLoad` in `ViewController`. Here is my `viewDidLoad` in `ViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self
}
```

And Xcode throws an error that myTableView is nil here. What can be reason for this? Seems like I don't know some well known concept in iOS development. It seems like it is not possible to present a `SomeViewController` from `ViewController` without segues, because `ViewController` was completely built using Storyboard, when `SomeViewController` does not have any storyboard. So, seems like, it is not possible to combine. Another idea is that it is just a Xcode bug. So, what is the reason for the error?

UPDATE:
Here is my ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"
    return cell 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    present(SomeViewController(), animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: Are you ***sure*** that's what's happening? Add a `print("in viewDidLoad")` inside your  `viewDidLoad()` func in `ViewController`. I'm betting you will only see that debug console output on initial load, and ***not*** when you call `present()`. Is it possible that you have a reference to `myTableView` in `SomeViewController`?

Comment: I am sure. I added and ready to show console output as an image. No reference. I tell you more. If I add 'if' statement to check is myTableView is nil or not viewDidLOad, SomeViewController is successfully presented. The reason for this is that viewDidLoad is called somehow and myTableView gets killed, but 'if ' statement just saves from the error. It is ridiculous.

Comment: I'd suggest trying this with a new project. I'm using the code you posted, and `viewDidLoad()` is ***definitely*** not being called when I present `SomeViewController`.

Comment: Is it possible you added a segue to your cell in `myTableView` in Storyboard?

Comment: I was playing with segues, but I don't think that have some segue here.

Comment: @DonMag I believe that it does not call viewDidLoad. It can't call actually because of design of iOS. But, I think it is some strange bug here and Xcode just behaves so. Possibly, I just don't use correctly tableview or its cells. Will try to create new project, but don't think that it is the reason. This is my second new project already to avoid this issue :)

Comment: It's definitely not an Xcode bug. As I said, I did a quick test and it works just fine... no extra call to `viewDidLoad()` and no Error due to `myTableView` being nil.

Comment: Just to be sure, I assume that `SomeViewController` is not a subclass of `ViewController`? It would make things easier if you showed the `SomeViewController` class

Comment: @Rafal Thanks. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

The `tableView` outlet is `nil` because your're creating instance of `SomeViewController` using `init` like `SomeViewController()`. This won't connect the `outlets` in your `controller`.

Instead create the instance of `SomeViewController` using the `storyboard`, i.e.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeVC") as? SomeViewController {
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set the `StoryboardID` of `SomeViewController` as `SomeVC` in `storyboard`.

Comment: But SomeViewController is not in a Storyboard.

Comment: If it is not, then creating @IBOutlet of tableView doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks, but you did not understand the question. @IBOutlet of tableView is in ViewController, not in a SomeViewController. SomeViewController does not have any outlets. All stuff in there made programatically. I just want to present it. That's all. But when I call present method, it calls viewDidLoad in ViewController, where tableView outlet became nil already. It is strange, I know. Possibly it is Xcode bug or I don't know something serious in iOS.

Comment: In that case, are you making any changes to ViewController's instance before didSelectRowAt is called?

Comment: I added my ViewController in a question. It is really simple. I just want to understand why this problem occurs. So I made some dummy ViewController just to show the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The reason was that I accidentally inherited SomeViewController from ViewController. Not UIViewController. Just ViewController. That of course forced to call viewDidLoad. Will never use default ViewController name.